# Clear-Content Powershell not working

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am new to Powershell.  I am referring to Clear-Content example mentioned in [this link](http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/powershell10/0026/)

I have a directory `d:\data\lab.`  Inside Lab different directories and subdirectories.  each directory and subdirectory contains `*.txt file`.

I want to write a powershell command which will empty content of all the txt files which are inside `d:\data\lab`

I am using bellow command

```
Clear-Content D:\data\Lab\* -Filter *.txt
```

I tried so many permutation and combination, but its not removing content of text files which are inside `d:\data\lab` folder.

Can anybody help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That function does not appear to support an option to recurse to subdirectories.  So it will only clear log content in the specified top-level dir.

You can use this one-liner to recursively clear log content (leave the file in place, but clears all content):

```
dir d:\data\lab -recurse -filter *.txt |%{ Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $null }
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbasic/thread/ad980266-45f5-417d-b7ff-2ce72b55ce01